# Delete and reanswer or edit after Question changed?

Tags: discussion, edits

There is a question on SO. Before the questoin was edited, it had a totaly diffrent meaning, which I answered with a not so good but correct answer. After the mentioned Edit, my answer was no more a answer to the question. In such a case, what should I do?

- Edit my answer, which already had some downvotes?
- Delete my old answer, and provide a new one?
- Any other sugests?

btw I am talking about that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590517/multiple-entry-with-the-id-in-php-tabl/32590608#32590608)

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have changed much beyond formatting. What specific changes do you think have affected your answer?

Comment: In general if you think your answer is invalidated by later edits then you should update your question to reflect that if possible or just delete it otherwise. In this particular case I would have have bothered answering in the first place a question with such obvious issues in the first place. @RobertLongson The table data changed after the answer was placed.

Comment: One of the column names changed slightly but, it's pretty much the same as it started out.

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't do edits that invalidate existing answers but I think what happened here is that the wording was so unclear you thought the OP meant one thing when they meant something else?

Comment: @bsmp yeah could be. This question here is more about the general case, if an edit invalidates an answer.